# How to connect to 2 different rabbitmq clusters from a service which has in the configuration defined spring.rabbitmq.addresses

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

we have some services sharing basic common configuration to connect with different external systems (DBs, Rabbitmq, etc) and common setup.

One of the variables we have for rabbitmq is spring.rabbitmq.addresses with the main cluster, which is overwritten when we want to connect to another cluster from a service, but we are connecting just to one of them.
 We are trying to modify one service to connect to 2 different clusters, but always prevails the value from spring.rabbitmq.addresses.

We tried following the documentation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#multiple-systems), with something like:

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses: host-rabbitmq2:5672

spring.cloud.stream:
  binders:
    rabbitInput:
      defaultCandidate: false
      type: rabbit
      environment.spring.rabbitmq.host: host-rabbitmq1:5672
    rabbitOutput:
      defaultCandidate: false
      type: rabbit
      environment.spring.rabbitmq.host: host-rabbitmq1:5672
    rabbitMainClusterInput:
      defaultCandidate: false
      type: rabbit
      environment.spring.rabbitmq.host: host-rabbitmq2:5672
```

But always was using the cluster defined in spring.rabbitmq.addresses.

Another attempt was setting an environment for the binder, something like:

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses: host-rabbitmq2:5672

 spring.cloud:
   config:
     override-system-properties: false
     allowOverride: true
     overrideNone: true
   stream:
     binders:
       rabbitDefaultInput:
         inheritEnvironment: false
         defaultCandidate: false
         type: rabbit
         environment.spring.rabbitmq:
           host: host-rabbitmq1:5672
           username: xxxxxx
           password: yyyyyy
```

With the same result.

Another attempt was putting both clusters in the variable spring.rabbitmq.addresses,

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses: host-rabbitmq2:5672,host-rabbitmq1:5672
```

but the result was that, it opened connections with the 2 clusters, but only connected with the queues in cluster that was the first in the list.

The question is, if there is any way to without removing the spring.rabbitmq.addresses variable, to connect to 2 different clusters using spring cloud stream?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addresses` overrides `host` and by default, the binders inherit the parent environment - have you tried using `addresses` in the binder environments instead of `host`?

You can also set `inheritEnvironment` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell , replacing host for addresses it worked and the service was able to connect and bind queues in both clusters